# Cannot implement Post method operation and consume api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, api, asp.net-web-api

I am using web API to call and implement a post method to insert values to MongoDB. The values fail to be inserted. 
Data is supposed to be inserted to an already created database in MongoDB! I am a beginner in web api n MongoDB.I need help

I have written code to insert values into Collection "contact".The code to consume API works but the code to perform post doesn't. The connection is established but the id value fails to be inserted.

```
**API code**
```

Contact.cs(Model class)

```
 public class Contact
    {
        [BsonId]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
```

MongoDbController(Controller)

```
public class MongoDbController : ApiController
    {
        readonly MongoDatabase mongoDatabase;

        public MongoDbController()
        {
            mongoDatabase = RetreiveMongohqDb();
        }

        private MongoDatabase RetreiveMongohqDb()
        {            
            MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
            return server.GetDatabase("mydb");
        }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public Contact Save(Contact contact)
        {
            var contactsList = mongoDatabase.GetCollection("contact");
            WriteConcernResult result;
            bool hasError = false;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Id))
            {
               contact.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
                result = contactsList.Insert<Contact>(contact);
                contactsList.Save(contact);              
                hasError = result.HasLastErrorMessage;
            }

            if (!hasError)
            {
                return contact;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
```

```
**Consuming API**
```

Contact.cs(Model class)

```
 public class Contact
    {
        [BsonId]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
```

TestController(controller)

```
  public class TestController : Controller
    {
      public ActionResult create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult create(Contact contact)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                //HTTP POST
                var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<Contact>("contact", contact);
                postTask.Wait();

                var result = postTask.Result;

                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }

            //ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server Error. Please contact administrator.");

            return View(contact);
        }

    }


     }
```

Create.cshtml(View)

```
@model TestApi.Models.Contact

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "create";
}

<h2>create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Contact</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

***Screenshots of my error is attached***
[image: api[![api_four]_one[image: ][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wRT3.png)

[image: api_three]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:61093/api/MongoDb/save")`

Comment: It was a careless mistake on my part. Thanks for your help!